# How to use google maps api (java script) to display map in flash

Tags: google-maps

i want `google maps api` (`javascript`) to display map but i want use `flash(swf)` file as front end is it possible? also i want create controls in `flash` and communctation with `javascript` to update map. I don't know whether it is possible or i am in completely wrong direction. Can any one help regarding this? One more thing, i planning to do it on `windows xp`as a demo project.

Comment: please see this link http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/flash/

Comment: But flash api was deprecated so i want use java script api but still want use flash front end is is possible?

Answer (score 0):

Please check official documentation of Google Map API for flash.

http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/flash/intro.html

Comment: yes buddy i got it. This Documentation is for Flash only as a frontend. you can choose Flash basic, event, overlay examples as per your need.

Comment: buddy I'm not a flash expert so i can not explain you in detail but you can refer URL http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/flash/basics.html. here you can find code and demo as well.

Answer (score 0):

Try this tutorial - http://active.tutsplus.com/tutorials/actionscript/google-maps-api-for-flash/

This should guide you step by step.

hope this helps.